# Overcoming "No owner defined between domain classes" in Grails many-to-many relationship

Tags: grails, entity-relationship

I was following the "Grails in Action" book in order to create the following scenario.

> A **map** belongs to one or many **mapsets**. A **mapset** can contain one or many **maps**. Both belong to a **user**.

So, what I did was:

`Map.groovy`:

```
static hasMany = [ sets : Mapset ]
static belongsTo = [ user : User, set : Mapset ]
```

`Mapset.groovy`:

```
static hasMany = [ maps : Map ]
static belongsTo = [ user : User ]
```

`User.groovy`:

```
static hasMany = [ maps : Map, sets: Mapset ]
```

Still, I receive this error when running the app:

> Caused by: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.exceptions.GrailsDomainException: **No owner defined between domain classes** [class at.package.Mapset] and [class at.package.Map] in a many-to-many relationship. Example: static belongsTo = at.package.Map

It doesn't change anything if I write the fully qualified class name for Map.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whoops, this is weird. The following the trick:

In `Map.groovy`:

```
static belongsTo = [ User, Mapset ]
```

<sub>I'd probably keep this as an answer instead of deleting the question because there's no reference for this error message on SO yet</sub>

Comment: set is surely a reserved word. So that's why (not 100% sure tough)

Comment: Yeah, that's what came to my mind afterwards, `Set` (capitalized) would have been probably even worse.